# New 14393 APIs (for ex: SystemIdentification) missing on VS2015 Update 3 with SDK 10.0.14393.33?

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, visual-studio-2015

There should be Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification according to this website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.aspx, but even I am using the latest Win10 OS (Anniversary 10.0.14393.82), VS 2015 Community Update 3, and Win 10 SDK 10.0.14393.33, I am not seeing it with intellisense.
Am I missing anything?

I tried adding these extensions, but it still does not show up:

- Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP
- Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP
- Windows Team Extensions for the UWP

(Added Info) UWP project Target version: 10586 and Min version: 10240

Comment: Do you have an actual issue, or is the issue that you cannot live without Intellisense? Anyway, since this API was *"introduced version 10.0.14393.0"*, what are your *Target Platform Version* and *Target Platform Min. Version* settings?

Comment: MinVer=10.0 Build 10240 and TargetVer=10.0 Build 10586. Obviously the problem is that the class itself is not available. To add some background, I am looking for any kind of hardware information/ unique id that I can retrieve in UWP framework.

Comment: Why are you surprised, that a class that was introduced in version *X* is unavailable when you set your target version to *Y* (where *Y* < *X*)?

Comment: So, regardless of the 14393 SDK and latest VS2015 update 3, because of my build target, I don't have the new API with me? VS does not provide me target version beyond 10586, so what is my option? Can you set your build target higher than 10586? This sounds.... weird and confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks to your hint, I think I might need to install this on top of VS 2015 update 3 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads?ocid=w10aeu_blog_oo_null_null_dmc_dl. Let me give it a try. But apparently it is the same VS 2015 Update 3. So, I am stuck not being able to utilize 14393 api at all?

Comment: See [General Property Page (Project)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x480de8.aspx) for explanations on those settings.

Comment: That link does not help. I think I will uninstall the SDK 14393.33 (bundled with VS2015 Community Update3) and reinstall the standalone SDK 14393.0 instead.

Comment: That's not going to help one bit. Read the link again. It explains the effect of the settings. You need to set the *Target Platform Version* to an SDK version that provides the functionality you want to use (10.0.14393.0 in your case).

Comment: Sorry if I sounded stubborn. So, like I said, the drop-down option 14393 is not available on my UWP project. I also did updating the target platform manually by opening up the csproj and change it to either 14393.33 or 14393.0, I cannot reload the project and it gave me the option to download the SDK. So, I am back to what I was trying to do, uninstall the Windows SDK 14393.33 which was bundled with VS and install the standalone SDK 14393.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @IInspectable, I figured out that my VS is not utilizing the latest 14393 SDK regardless being installed.

In  short, the answer is **reinstall the SDK**.

The steps I did to resolve my problem is:

1. Uninstall Windows SDK 14393.33 through Settings->Apps & Features->... uninstall. I could not uninstall through the VS Setup wizard for some reason.
2. Install the standalone SDK through https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=822845.
3. Apparently, it did not solve my issue yet, because now every project is not openable. Therefore I rerun the VS Setup Wizard using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads?ocid=w10aeu_blog_oo_null_null_dmc_dl and reinstall the bundled SDK 14393 (and the phone emulator with it)
4. Now when I reopen my solution (and projects), voila the option 14393 is available to me now.
5. I also confirmed that the class I am looking for: SystemIdentification is available after I changed the target version to 14393.